# How to increment amount every hour in PHP?

Tags: php

Hello I have this simple code in php that increments an amount every hour by 5 values. I used time and convert it into an integer using the code below. How do I use the if-else condition to make it dynamic?

Example, I have a default of `3 hours` for an amount of `30`. The amount will increase by `5` every hour. What syntax should be best for using this? Please help, I am very new to php language.

```
<?php
$totalamount = '';

$seconds = strtotime('08:00:00 AM') - strtotime('01:00:00 PM');
echo $hours = abs(floor($seconds/3600));

if($hours == 3) {
  $totalamount = 30.00;
} elseif($hours == 4) {
  $totalamount = 35.00;
} elseif($hours == 5) {
  $totalamount = 40.00;
}
echo ' '.$totalamount;
?>
```

Comment: What is the amount for an hour? Then do you don't even need loops. Just simple math.

Comment: What are you trying to make dynamic?

Comment: the amount would increase by values of 5 every hour.

Comment: This essentially does what you want, but you probably don't want to hardcode two timestamps. Instead, you have some *start time*, and you have ***now*** (whenever you run your script again), and you can easily calculate how much the price should have increased between then and now. Don't think in terms in incrementing something exactly on the hour every hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to calculate the total amount at a specific point, then you just need a single if and in that multiply the increment (5) by the number of hours over 3...

```
$seconds = strtotime('08:00:00 AM') - strtotime('01:00:00 PM');
echo $hours = abs(floor($seconds/3600));
$totalamount = 30;

if($hours > 3) {
    $totalamount += ($hours-3)*5;
} 
echo ' '.$totalamount;
```

Comment: I didn't know that += is also applicable for php. I think I'm gonna go some serious digging about php language. Thanks for this

Comment: The amount doesn't seem to match sir @Nigel Ren , its a 12 hour format in time so if starttime is `12:00:00AM` and endtime is `02:00:00 AM` it gives me an amount of `130`

Answer (score 1):

From the three examples you gave, it looks like this is a simple linear function, so you could just use something like this

```
function getAmountForHours( $hours ){
    return $hours * 5 + 15;
}
```

So you could just call

```
$totalamount = '';

$seconds = strtotime('08:00:00 AM') - strtotime('01:00:00 PM');
echo $hours = abs(floor($seconds/3600));
echo ' ' . getAmountForHours($hours);
```

Comment: Only problem is that this doesn't take into account being less than 3 hours apart, if it was `strtotime('08:00:00 AM') - strtotime('09:00:00 AM');` you would have 20.

Comment: @NigelRen I totally agree with you. I tried to focus on the "How do I [...] make it dynamic?" part of the question only, since I was not entirely sure if this is an actual requirement or just came across as one.

Comment: The amount doesn't seem to match sir @Nigel Ren , its a 12 hour format in time so if starttime is 12:00:00AM and endtime is 02:00:00 AM it gives me an amount of 130